# How to find number of distinct values from a collection

Tags: backbone.js

Suppose I have a collection like:

```js
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "jonas",
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "jonas",
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "name": "smirk",
  }
```

How do I get :

Number of distinct names, like in this case, 2

The distinct names, in this case, jonas and smirk ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some Backbone and Underscore magic, combining [`collection.pluck`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck) and [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq):

> **pluck** collection.pluck(attribute)
>   Pluck an attribute from each model in the collection. Equivalent to calling map, and returning a single attribute from the iterator.
>
> **uniq**  _.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iterator])
>   Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality.
>   [...]

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 1, name: "jonas"},
    {id: 2, name: "jonas"},
    {id: 3, name: "smirk"}
]);

var names = _.uniq(c.pluck('name'));
console.log(names.length);
console.log(names);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/PSFXg/